# The method from the type is not visible error when i am using two different packages

Tags: javascript, java, package

I am totally new to programming.So my question is i tried to create two classes added them in to two seperate packages.but after i tried to call one of them in to another it shows the method display() from the type hai is not visible.

```
package mypkg;

public class hai {

    void display() {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

and the next class is

```
package mypkg2;

import mypkg.hai;

public class hello {
    
    hello(){
        hai a=new hai();
        a.display();
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        hello b=new hello();
    }
    

}
```

Here i tried to call **hai** class from **mypkg** and tried to run display function and print **Hello world** . but getting the mentioned error.so how to use this class properly to display **Hello world** from the other class ?

Comment: The Correction was so simple,just added **public** infront of my display function  

    package mypkg;
    
    public class hai {
    
        public void display() {
            System.out.println("Hello world");
        }
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default scope for a java method is package-private. So it will only be visible to classes in the same package.

Try defining it as a **public** method.